# Copy all records from Master table to a Clone table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

With SQL I can copy data from one table to another mirror table. (e.g. `insert into TABLE_EXAMPLE_COPY select * from TABLE_EXAMPLE;` .
How can I do the same thing using Hibernate `org.hibernate.Criteria` or `org.hibernate.Query` or `org.hibernate.SQLQuery`?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to perform that action from within the boundaries of JPA or Hibernate, the best way to accomplish that is to use a Native SQL statement.

```
session
  .createNativeQuery( "INSERT INTO table_copy SELECT * FROM table" ).
  .executeUpdate();
```

The other options involve reading the source table into a POJO and then transforming that into the POJO representation for the copy table and saving those rows.  The problem with these is that you also introduce network latency and JVM overhead just to create an in-memory object, transform it, and then push it back over the network to the database.

The presented above solution avoids all those drawbacks and allows the database to handle all that in the best performing way it knows how.

Comment: Yes, I was worried about that POJO's that creates behind the process, each POJO have 62 property and there are 5000 - 600,000 POJO to be cloned. So, thank u for good suggestion.